# URL Rewriting issue (Apache2 / Debian 10)

Tags: apache, url, rewriting

I got a basic problem that I can't resolve.

I set up a LAMP server on a Debian 10 machine which run into a Docker container.

PHP and the services Apache and MySQL are functionnal, but I got a problem with the URL rewriting.
It don't run, even on the basic entry point of my web server which is : "http://localhost/"

If I use the real adress, It work, but if I brink a "virtual" adress like "http://localhost/toto" for exemple, I got a 404 error from Apache.
Here is the content of my .htaccess file that I put on the root of my base directory "/var/www/html" :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.css|.js|.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.svg|.ttf|.woff|.woff2|.pdf|.zip|.mp4|.avi|.ogg)$
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

In the configuration file of my default website (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf), I've the directive "DocumentRoot /var/www/html".

If I do a phpinfo(), I see the "mod_rewrite" in the loaded_module.

Is anybody know how can I solve it ?

Mickaël

Answer (score 0):

Finally..., It's OK !

My .htacess file was just ignored by Apache, because the AllowOverride statement was set to "None" by default in my "apache2.conf".

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I changed it by "AllowOverride All", I restarded Apache and I could valid that the rewriting work fine.